# add new_foo_path manually in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, when you create a model using scaffold like the following:

rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string

It will generate the: models, controllers, and views

The views for example, in the index.html.erb file there is table which lists all the Users registers. For each user there are links: Show, Edit, Destroy

in the index.html.erb these are represented by the following lines:

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %></td>
 <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', student, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

and there also is a New User link which is represented by:

```
<%= link_to 'New Student', new_student_path %>
```

However, if I create a model,view and controller manually without the scaffold, then these 'paths' won't be generated.
By 'paths' I mean:   new_student_path,   edit_student_path(student), student

How do I generate these manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `config/routes.rb`.
You can add e.g. this:

```
resources :students
```

You can see more this at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You can type rake routes at the command line to see what routes are available before and after doing this.
Basically you will get the following routes:

```
HTTP VerbPath   action  used for 
GET     /photos         index   display a list of all photos 
GET     /photos/new     new     return an HTML form for creating a new photo 
POST    /photos         create  create a new photo 
GET     /photos/:id     show    display a specific photo 
GET     /photos/:id/edit edit   return an HTML form for editing a photo 
PUT     /photos/:id     update  update a specific photo 
DELETE  /photos/:id     destroy delete a specific photo
```

Comment: I get the following errror:  ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#new

Missing partial users/form with

Comment: Then it's working :)  Do you have the file views/users/new.html.erb and views/users/_form.html.erb ?

Comment: You are missing the file views/users/_form.html.erb, but this isnt related to the routing.

Comment: yes.. but it seems to crash on this line : <%= render 'form' %>

Comment: ah... okey... thnx for ur help !

Answer (score 1):

When you add the resources to  `config/routes.rb` the paths will get generated automatically.

Let's say that you have added a controller named `StudentsController` manually.
To get new_student_path, edit_student_path etc. you need to add this line to `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :students
```

This adds the paths for the seven restful actions. 
You can read more on the rails routing on this url: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Andreas, apologies, I edited the wrong post and put my information in your answer.  My Mistake.  I've tried to restore your closer to the original.  Again, apologies, was simply a mistake.

Comment: Again, apologies, It was a mistake.  They happen.  I was about to improve your answer more back to original but I see you have done that already.

Comment: I gave you an upvote as an apology.  So at least you get some reward for your help.